# Send message via php

Tags: php

I have problem with sending messages via php from host email to someone email with script. Like for registration code etc...

Here is my code:

```
        $to = "$email";
    $from = "support@webiste.com";
    $subject = 'Web Site';
    $message = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>WebSite</title></head><body style="padding: 20px;"><h1>WEBSITE</h1><p>Hello '.$name.' '.$lname.'</p><h3>Click the link below to activate your account: </h3><p><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.website.com/MB/activation.php?id='.$rewr.'&re='.$re.'">Click Here</a></p></body></html>';
    $headers = "From: $from\n";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){

echo "Sent";}else echo "failed";
```

I got failed message every time

Comment: every server do not support  mail() function

Comment: is there different one or?

Comment: use mailgun / phpmailer m familar with this two. mailgun gives you 10K email for free every month

Answer (score 0):

sendmail is server dependent a better solution would be to use Pear mail.

```
include_once 'Mail.php';
include_once 'Mail/mime.php' ;

$recipients  = '<' . $this->to . '>'; 

$text =  $this->message['text'];
$html =  $this->message['html'];

$crlf = "\n";

$hdrs = array('From' => $this->from,'To' => $this->to,'Subject' =>         $this->subject);
$mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));

if(!empty($text)){$mime->setTXTBody($text);}
if(!empty($html)){$mime->setHTMLBody($html);}

$body = $mime->get();
$hdrs = $mime->headers($hdrs);

$params["host"] = MailSMTP; 
$params["port"] =  MailPort;
$params["auth"] = true;  
$params["username"] = $username; 
$params["password"] = $password; 

$mail =& Mail::factory('smtp',$params);
$value = $mail->send($recipients,$hdrs, $body);

if(PEAR::isError($value)) { 
return false;
}
```

Above is code that I use myself. It will send multi-part mail ie HTML and plain text so they can read it on any device and it uses Pear mail and also send to 1 or multiple recipients. Pear is an extension of PHP.